# Using pointers in an ABB (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree

I've been studying binary search trees. I created this function to delete nodes but I found a mistakes when delete leaf nodes (for example, the biggest) value. The error is that when I print the tree and i've deleted some leaf nodes, I print some null values.
This is the function for delete values:

```
void deleteValues(Nodo* p, int valor){
    bool bo;
    Nodo* otro = nullptr;
    Nodo* aux = nullptr;
    Nodo* aux1 = nullptr;
    if(p != nullptr){ 
        if(valor < p->info){ 
            deleteValues(p->izq, valor);
        }
        else{
            if(valor > p->info){
                deleteValues(p->der, valor);
            }
            else{
                otro = p;
                if(otro->der == nullptr){
                    p = otro->izq;
                }
                else{
                    if(otro->izq == nullptr){
                        p = otro->der;
                    }
                    else{
                        aux = p->izq;
                        bo = false;
                        while(aux->der != nullptr){
                            aux1 = aux;
                            aux = aux->der;
                            bo = true;
                        }
                        p->info = aux->info;
                        otro = aux;
                        if(bo){
                            aux1->der = aux->izq;
                        }
                        else{
                            p->izq = aux->izq;
                        }
                    }
                }
                delete(otro);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is the function for printing values in inorder:

```
void inorder(Nodo *p){ 
    if(p != nullptr){
        if(p->izq != nullptr){
            inorder(p->izq);   
        }
        cout << "[" << p->info << " "<< &p->info << "]"<<endl; 
        if(p->der != nullptr){
            inorder(p->der);
        }
    }
}
```

The output seems like this:
Before delete 7:
[1 0x5582468b7730]
[2 0x5582468b76d0]
[4 0x5582468b7710]
[6 0x5582468b7750]
[7 0x5582468b7770]

After delete 7:
[1 0x5582468b7730]
[2 0x5582468b76d0]
[4 0x5582468b7710]
[6 0x5582468b7750]
[2 0x5582468a5010]
[1183545072 0x5582468b7770]

I think could be a mistake with the use of pointers, but I'm not really sure.
The output is like this:

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You delete a node, but don't update a pointer to that node from its parent. The parent ends up with a dangling pointer. Then `inorder` follows this pointer that used to point to a valid node but no longer does, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that after deleting a node you are not updating its pointer in its parent node. For example, consider p is a tree with only one node. (i.e., root node is a leaf node) As you pass the `Node *p` to `DeleteValues`, it deletes the contents of that node. But your tree root pointing to some some address with deleted memory, instead of pointing to a nullptr. You can solve this issue by passing a double-pointer as the node. Consider using the prototype `void DeleteValues(Node **dp, int valor);`. In its implementation, update `*dp = nullptr;` after `delete(*dp);`. I'm just pointing out the mistake with the help of the base case; you need take care of all the cases.